# Blockchain fabric samples: Latest chaincode not getting picked by by ./startFabric.sh

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, docker-toolbox, ibm-blockchain

I am running Docker Toolbox on Windows. I have downloaded fabric samples from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples. Modified the fabcar chaincode.

The first time I ran ./startFabric.sh to bring up the local blokchain network, the chaincode is getting picked up well and fine.

Now I make further changes to fabcar chaincode. But this time, my latest chaincode changes are not being picked up by the blockchain network. I still see old log messages and responses.

I have tried the following options already:
1) clearing up docker containers 
2) restarting docker toolbox.
3) rerunning ./startFabric.sh from scratch.

The only time my chaincode changes are picked up is the "first ever time" when i use that particular chaincode. Thereafter the first chaincode somehow resides in the memory forever.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After changing chaincode in fabric-samples/chaincode/fabcar/go/fabcar.go (this is where you change the chaincode, I presume), you have to go build fabcar.go so that latest compiled code gets into the peer.

Answer (score 0):

`./startFabric.sh` add a new docker image and use it as chaincode container.
To run updated chaincode, remove this container and execute `./startFabric.sh` again.

```
docker rmi -f dev-peer0.org1.example.com-docchain-1.0-961b279a2d42ac81dd6585a11d9fad6bfe4f000a2c3d0cdc9be4bd1ecdf5610d
```